# Include artifact in shaded jar but do not cause dependency for those using the project

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, maven-shade-plugin

This question is very similar to question [Maven Include Dependency in Shaded Jar Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562790/maven-include-dependency-in-shaded-jar-only).

My problem was that I wanted to have slf4j-simple included in shaded jar as it is meant for standalone execution and needed proper logging.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I tried using `<scope>provided</scope>` but then failed to make maven-shade-plugin to include it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was using  `<optional>true</optional>` in the dependency declaration. Since scope was enough for me previously, I was unaware of this option.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```